# Slack: How to open replies with the keyboard (without mouse)?

Tags: slack

How can I open the "7 replies" with the keyboard (without a mouse)?

[image: slack]

I am using the slack web-app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys to move through messages. When you reach the message with thread replies (in your case, *7 replies*), press the <kbd>right</kbd> arrow key to open thread messages panel.